# Может ли логическое ударение падать на качественное наречие?

Tags: грамотная-речь, наречия, обстоятельство

В неких пособиях написано, что качественные наречия не требуют ударения, однако обстоятельственные слова требуют. А проблема в том, что качественные наречия являются обстоятельством.

Ясное дело, качественные наречия иногда требуют лог. ударения, например в перечислении, противопоставлении, указывающем контексте и т.д., однако интересно одно: правда ли это?

Например, в них также написано, что на глагол не может падать логическое ударение в распространённых предложениях.

Такое предложение: "Я быстро закончу".

Распространённое предложение и качественное наречие.

Поясните, пожалуйста, кто понимает данную систему! Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: NewellOster, можете дать ссылку на эти "некие пособия"? Просто непонятно, как логическое ударение связано с частями речи. Оно может падать на любое слово, порой даже независимо от позиции в предложении и его распространенности.

Comment: https://prolog-vesna.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Rechevoe-masterstvo-uchitelya-ch.-2.pdf

Автор данного пособия ЯГТИ

Comment: Ой, у меня, чтобы посмотреть, требуется загрузка файла – не хочется этого делать...

Comment: Извините, у меня больше не имеется ссылок.
Вот названия, поищите, пожалуйста:
"Речевое мастерство учителя и работа со словом" Викторовой О. В.

Comment: Нашёл, посмотрел. Там написано то, о чём я сказал выше: "Логическое ударение может стоять на любом значимом слове, где бы оно ни находилось - в начале, середине или в конце..." А вот по поводу качественных наречий большие сомнения. Например: "Я ехал **быстро**" – явное ударение на наречии. И в Вашем примере "Я **быстро** закончу" – тоже.

Comment: Я единодушен с Вашими словами, ибо созвучно лишь на наречиях, однако таких противоречий не может быть. Возможно, что дело в чём-то другом, чего я не могу понять.

Comment: Возможно... Подождём, что скажут другие участники.

Comment: А можете процитировать абзац об отсутствии логического ударения у кач.наречий?

Comment: Если в предложении имеются дополнения или обстоятельства, поясняющие глагол, то ударение получают именно они, а не глагол. Сами же глаголы выделяются только в нераспространенных предложениях, когда они стоят на втором месте, а также при противопоставлении и перечислении. Наречия при глаголе требуют ударения, если они по смыслу почти заменяют глагол. Но качественные наречия не требуют ударения. @Atoma

Comment: А здесь "скрытое противопоставление", читайте дальше.

Comment: "Не требуют" не значит, что не может падать, это значит, что не падает в обязательном порядке.